i can't debug using android emulator
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'test_udacoding'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find dev.flutter:flutter-gradle-plugin:3.10.0.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/dev/flutter/flutter-gradle-plugin/3.10.0/flutter-gradle-plugin-3.10.0.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/dev/flutter/flutter-gradle-plugin/3.10.0/flutter-gradle-plugin-3.10.0.pom
- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/dev/flutter/flutter-gradle-plugin/3.10.0/flutter-gradle-plugin-3.10.0.pom
Required by:
project :


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I've tried changing the Flutter version but it still doesn't work

Your title is totally wrong. Your problem is not debugging or the emulator but building the project. Second your question only consists of the error output but misses a self-written text describing what you want to to and details on your environment.
